# Arrange menu horizontally/detect arrow keys

Tags: linux, bash

I want to make a small game using bash script, The game, at the beginning provides 4 options for users to choose by using the four arrow keys such `left`, `right`, `down`, `up`.

ex)

```
1) Join 
2) Sign in
3) Sign out
4) Exit
```

How can I arrange 4 options above like

```
1) Join                 2) Sign in

3) Sign out             4) Exit
```

and detects the user's arrow keys when in one of them?

Comment: This is beyond plain bash.

Comment: bash is the wrong language for this.   If you want to write some games, you might want to look at [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/), a library for writing games in python with a very active community and hundreds of examples to learn from.  Alternatively, look at [godot](https://godotengine.org/) an open source game engine that can be used for games ranging from extremely simple to extremely complicated.  It also has a very active community and hundreds of examples.  BTW, both pygame and godot have good documentation and tutorials, including video tutorials on youtube.

Comment: Both of these are available as packages for most Linux distros so are easily installed.  Finally, If they're too complicated for your needs, any language with a decent curses library will do - including python and perl.   You *could* write a really simple game (if it didn't require data structures more complex than scalar variables and simple arrays. and if you didn't mind it being extremely slow) with bash and dialog or zenity or similar, but you really shouldn't - shell is only good for coordinating the execution of other programs. It's terrible at anything else.